# Shut Down dialog box on login screen not giving any options

Tags: upgrade, 14.04, shutdown

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 from 13.10, and when I am logged in the shut down dialog box has the correct buttons that you can click - but from the login screen, there are no buttons to click.

Due to being new here, the screenshot is available separately:  [image]

Comment: Have you tried shutting down via command line?

Comment: To clarify this further, command-line shutdown works if I log in with root privileges - but these buttons are missing when nobody is logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file `/etc/pam.d/common-session` add:

```
session optional pam_systemd.so
```

This seems to have been missed during one of the upgrades this system has gone through.

ref: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1321454